# Is Anaconda necessary to be installed to PC besides Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am new to Python. I am a very old R programmer. One of my PhD courses is performed via Python.

So, I installed Jupyter Notebook; I wrote simple "Hello World" in Jupyter Notebook. I wonder whether I must install Anaconda or not?

I ask this because: I looked at Anaconda's IDE in youtube, and it shows RStudio, Jupyter Notebook, etc. in a bundled manner. In RStudio, one can perform all the package handlings within RStudio.

So, I wondered is there a way to install python packages within Jupyter Notebook, or should I really install Anaconda? What is the benefit of installing Anaconda (besides Jupyter Notebook)?

Comment: Have you checked the Anaconda/Conda documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python packages are not installed with python functions, like it would be the case in R with `install.packages("package name")`. Instead, an external package manager usually is used to install and possibly compile the package files to a directory where python can import it from.

Anaconda offers (among others) the package manager `conda`. Most popular is `pip`. Some Linux distributions also offer python packages via their package manager (e.g. `apt` on Debian/Ubuntu). All these package managers download packages from their own repositories, so `conda install numpy`, `pip install numpy` and `apt install python3-numpy` all install a package `numpy`, but from different sources and in possibly different versions.

Jupyter Notebook is a programming environment, where you can execute shell commands with `!command`, so depending on the system where the Jupyter server is running, you can use `!pip install numpy`, `!conda install numpy` or other commands as cells in the Jupyter Notebook you are working in. This will run the command in a shell.

That graphical menu with Jupyter, RStudio etc. you describe is the program "Anaconda Navigator", which is installed with Anaconda. Jupyter is just a Python library, which is pre-installed with Anaconda, but can also be installed via `pip`, `apt` and other package managers.

Answer (score 2):

The packages in python are generally installed with "pip" (or "conda") in the terminal and are then available regardless where you run your script from. Assuming you don't have multiple python versions set up on your PC, they should then all be available in your jupyter-notebook also.

If you don't want to open another window to do this, you can also run BASH code from Jupyter itself, just start the line with an exclamation mark (!)

i.e.

```
!pip install pandas
```

The benefits of Anaconda are that it bundles everything you need to at least start your more basic projects (python release, basic packages, IDE) and that you can set-up project-specific environments that do not interfere with your system-wide package installations.

Answer (score 1):

Like Virtualenv, Anaconda also uses the concept of creating environments so as to isolate different libraries and versions. Anaconda also introduces its own package manager, called conda, from where you can install libraries.
Additionally, Anaconda still has the useful interaction with pip that allows you to install any additional libraries which are not available in the Anaconda package manager.

It is a good option for setting up of a better environment for working with jupyter.

Comment: So, is Anaconda a supportive base for Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Yes kind of because it is one of the best environments for jupyter notebook